# JSON nested object post to node.js server?

Tags: json, node.js

I want to POST an Object via JSON to node.js server.

The Object structure is nested, and never succeeded to receive and parse correctly on node.js server site.

---

EDIT2

I found a solution: see the answer section...

---

EDIT

I found

```
     console.log(body);
```

itself output

val1=hello&val2%5Bval3%5D=world

//= {"val1":"hello","val2[val3]":"world"}

weired JSON way

---

client.js

```
    var data ={val1:"hello",val2:{val3:"world"}};
    console.log(data); // -> *1
    $.ajax({
        url:"/",
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:data,
        success:function (res)
        {
            resHandler(res);
        }
    });
```

---

*1 ChromeDevelopersTool

Object

val1: "hello"

val2: Object

val3: "world"

---

server.js

```
var onreq = function (req, res)
{
    if(req.method == 'POST')
    {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data)
        {
            body += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function ()
        {
            var json = qs.parse(body);
            console.log(json.val1); //hello
            console.log(json.val2); //undefined
            console.log(json.val3); //undefined

            console.log(JSON.stringify(json)); 
            //{"val1":"hello","val2[val3]":"world"}
        });
    }
```

---

I understand

val2[val3]
is
val2.val3

However,

---

Problem 1

JSON.stringify prints out

{"val1":"hello","val2[val3]":"world"}

not

{val1:"hello",val2:{val3:"world"}}

It's ugly, and I don't know why it's like that.

---

Problem 2

I can never get {val3:"world"}

console.log(json.val3); //undefined

---

Anyone can explain, and how can I POST a nested JSON to node.js server?

Thanks.

Comment: dont use `qs.parse` use `JSON.parse` -.-

Comment: `JSON.stringify` yields `"{"val1":"hello","val2":{"val3":"world"}}"` for me which is correct

Comment: I've already tried JSON.parse on bunch of places including replacing qs.parse. In that case,   the output is  >undefined
>Caught exception: Unexpected token v

Comment: @kenokabe: Please remove the solution from your question and post it as an answer.

Comment: ThiefMaster: Thanks. I've done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do NOT use JSON typed data on jQuery Ajax, instead use Stringified JSON

I created a WIKI

http://code.google.com/p/kenokabe/wiki/nestedJSONproblem